# Square array making the same columns and rows

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make a square array that shows me at the output:
1.

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2
1 2 3 3 3
1 2 3 4 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

I was thinking about this solution, but the output is wrong:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] nowatablica = new int[7][7];
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < nowatablica.length;i++ ) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nowatablica.length; j++) {
                nowatablica[i][j] = i+j;                                 
                System.out.print(nowatablica [i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me where I can find the probelem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `nowatablica[i][j] = i+j;`. You are not calculating the value right. If you look at the array, you notice that the value 1 exists only in row 0 and column 0, the value 2 exists only in cells [1, x] and [x, 1], with x>=1 etc.

The correct expression is thus `nowatablica[i][j] = Math.min(i, j)+1;`

Comment: I am new here? What should I do, to make it?

Comment: @DanielMateusz to accept an answer as the solution, click on the check mark on the left of the answer